# Ordering posts by custom field named "date" in backend

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, meta-query, order, date

I defined a custom field named "date" and now want to order the post list in the backend by this field.

I defined the filters to make ordering work and header is clickable and shows the order arrow icon. The problem is that the post list gets ordered by *publish date* instead of custom field "date".

```
function crimes_columns($columns) {
    $columns['crimedate'] = 'Crime date';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'crimes_columns');

function crimes_show_columns($name) {
    global $post;
    switch ($name) {
        case 'crimedate':
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "date", true);
            break;
    }
    return $row_output;
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'crimes_show_columns');

add_filter( 'manage_edit-sortable_columns', 'crimes_add_custom_column_make_sortable' );
function crimes_add_custom_column_make_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['crimedate'] = 'crimedate';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'crimes_orderby_meta' );
function crimes_orderby_meta( $query ) {
    if(!is_admin())
        return;
 
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');
 
    if( 'crimedate' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','date');
        $query->set('meta_type', 'DATE');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value_date');
    }
}
```

Do you think the problem is the name of the field, do I have to rename the field to make it work? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: That `meta_value_date` should be `meta_value`, but why do you need another date field?

Comment: I also tried with `$query->set('orderby','meta_value');` - and without `meta_type`, but without success. To keep it simple I didn't tell that the custom field "date" is defined in a CPT.

Comment: I don't know why using `meta_value` doesn't work for you, but you need to specify the correct meta type for the sorting to works as expected. So what is the format of that meta value, is it like `20201013`?

Comment: The format is `mmddYYYY`, e.g. `10132020`. So do I have to convert it into a MySQL timestamp with format `Y-m-d h:i:s`? How could I do this conversion?

Comment: Well, if you use a plugin for creating the custom field UI, then you should check the plugin site for documentation on the available date formats. But seems like you can try with `YYYY-mm-dd`..

Comment: I use jquery-ui datepicker to save the date. Ok, so one solution would be to rewrite all dates in format `YYYY-mm-dd`. But is there any solution without changing the format and ordering the result query with the choosen format `mmddYYYY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue in your code is this part: `$query->set('orderby','meta_value_date');` whereby you should use `meta_value` and not `meta_value_date`. (There is `meta_value_num`, but that's not suitable for used with sorting by dates.)

Then make sure the `meta_type` is set to `DATE` (which yes, you already done it correctly), **and** use the right date format — `10132020` is really not a good date and MySQL/MariaDB also won't be able to cast such values to a valid date — WordPress/`WP_Query` instructs MySQL/MariaDB to *cast the value as a date* when the meta type is set to `date`.

And in reply to (your comment): "*But is there any solution without changing the format and ordering the result query with the chosen format mmddYYYY?*", sorry, but I don't think there's an easy way to do so.

And the better practice is use the proper format when saving the metadata and not when retrieving it. For example, you could use the [ISO 8601 date format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) which is also used by [`current_time( 'mysql' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/) in WordPress: `Y-m-d` — but that's with PHP; with the jQuery Datepicker widget, you would use [`yy-mm-dd` or `$.datepicker.ISO_8601`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) which then gives a date like `2020-10-14` for October 14th 2020.

So correct the date format and use `meta_value` with the `orderby` parameter, and the sorting would work as expected.

### Other issues in your code

1. In `crimes_show_columns()`, if you need to access the full post data, use `get_post()` and not the `global` call. So for example, you can rewrite the function to:

   ```php
   function crimes_show_columns( $name, $post_id ) {
   //  $post = get_post( $post_id ); // like this
   //  global $post;                 // not this

       switch ( $name ) {
           case 'crimedate':
               echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'date', true );
               break;
       }

       // action hooks do not need anything be returned back
   //  return $row_output; // moreover, $row_output is not defined anywhere..
   }
   add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column',  'crimes_show_columns', 10, 2 );
   ```
2. The correct hook (used for adding a custom sortable column *name*) is `manage_edit-post_sortable_columns` and not `manage_edit-sortable_columns` because on the `edit.php?post_type=post` admin screen, the screen ID is `edit-post`; i.e. `<name of the PHP file without .php>-<post type>`.